# ¿Como evaluar condicionales en Java en este ejercicio?

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con este ejercicio.(Adjunto enunciado)

***El dueño de un estacionamiento requiere un programa que le permita determinar
cuánto debe cobrar por el uso del estacionamiento a sus clientes. 
Las tarifas que se tienen son las siguientes:
Las dos primeras horas a $5.00 c/u.
Las siguientes tres a $4.00 c/u.
Las cinco siguientes a $3.00 c/u.
Después de diez horas el costo por cada una es de dos dólares.
Lea datos del cliente y las horas de parqueo. Presente la salida respectiva.***

He evaluado muy bien la primera condición pero en las otras tengo un problema. Cuando compilo y le pongo que necesito 5 horas de estacionamiento me arroja un total de 18 dolares, se supone que 5 está comprendido en la segunda condicional y me deben de salir 14 tal y como lo he puesto. El otro problema es similar, en la tercera condicional necesito 9 horas de estacionamiento y me sale 34 cuando debería de salirme 17. Espero puedan ayudarme, adjunto el código.

```
package estacionamiento;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Estacionamiento {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Declaración de variables tipo cadena, enteras y flotantes//
    String nombrecliente, ced;
    int horas;
    double cobroestacionamiento=0;
    //Ingreso de los Datos//
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite un nombre y apellido: ");
    nombrecliente=entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese CI: "); 
    ced=entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.print("¿Por cuantas horas usará el estacionamiento?: ");
    horas = entrada.nextInt();
    //CALCULO CONDICIONAL//
    if(horas<=2)
        cobroestacionamiento=horas*5.00;                
    if(horas>2&&horas<=5)
        cobroestacionamiento=2*5+(horas-3)*4.00;
    if(horas>5&&horas<=10)
        cobroestacionamiento=2*5+3*4+(horas-5)*3.00;
    if(horas>10)
        cobroestacionamiento=2*5+3*4+3*5+(horas-10)*2.00;
    System.out.println("---------DATOS DEL CLIENTE---------");
    System.out.println("Nombres_Cliente:" +nombrecliente);
    System.out.println("Cedula_Cliente:" +ced);
    System.out.println("Sus horas de parqueo son: " +horas+' '+"horas");
    System.out.println("Total a pagar: " +cobroestacionamiento+' '+"dolares");       
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(horas>2&&horas<=5)
        cobroestacionamiento=2*5+(horas-3)*4.00;`

serían horas -2 puesto que son 2 horas las que cuestan 10 no 3

`if(horas>2&&horas<=5)
        cobroestacionamiento=2*5+(horas-2)*4.00;`

Aparte de eso no estas haciendo los cálculos bien, si las 2 primeras valen 10 euros y las 3 siguientes 4, las 5 horas serian 22 euros, a continuación te dejo las respectivas salidas de cada una de las horas y su bloque de código retocado, saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 if(horas>10){

    cobroestacionamiento = 37 + ((horas)-10)*2;

 }else if(horas>5){

    cobroestacionamiento = 22 + ((horas-5)*3);


 }else if(horas>2){


    cobroestacionamiento =  10 + ((horas-2) * 4);

 }else{

   cobroestacionamiento = horas * 5;

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza las clausulas `else`, son necesarias allí, piensa en el rendimiento y eficiencia del código.
También replantea la manera como condicionas la cantidad de horas, mas o menos así:

```
if(horas>10) {
  cobroestacionamiento = 2*5+3*4+3*5+(horas-10)*2.00);
} else if(horas>5) {
  cobroestacionamiento = 2*5+3*4+(horas-5)*3.00);
} else if(horas>2) {
  cobroestacionamiento = 2*5+(horas-3)*4.00);
} else {
  cobroestacionamiento = horas*5.00;
}
```

De ese modo el flujo del programa cambia de manera significativa.